# Qual é a vantagem de utilizar a função setState() para modificar um array?

Tags: javascript, react

Verifiquei que é possível modificar um array no `state` de duas formas:

1. `this.setState({meuArray: [...meuArray, 'novoValor']}); // ...meuArray é o espalhamento de meuArray`
2. `this.state.meuArray.push('novovalor');`

Qual das duas formas acima tem maior eficiência?

Comment: A segunda forma é completamente desencorajada no ecossistema do React, já que você estaria mutando o estado – algo completamente abominado nessa situação. A primeira pode trazer problemas de performance (em alguns casos), mas se eu fosse você, mantê-la-ia, já que buscar por otimizações prematuras nem sempre é uma boa opção.

Comment: Pra enfileirar as mudanças do estado e assim atualizar a UI, lembrando que o primeiro argumento aceita função e closures para aplicar com return, faz parte do "ciclo de vida" dos componentes. Usam uma nova "inovadora" (dão nome pra algo que provavelmente já existia de outra forma e fazem um marketing danado em cima pra dizer que isso é melhor que qualquer coisa pra ganhar adeptos) metodologia chamado "functional programming", leia mais em [tag:programação-funcional]

Comment: Na verdade tenho estudado programação funcional ao longo dos anos, desde a universidade até hoje sempre a estudar e aprender.

Comment: O que mais detesto no Stackoverflow em português é que fazem downvotes por tudo e por nada. A pergunta está mal formulada? Se alguém não acha uma pergunta interessante é motivo suficiente para votar negativamente? Não seria melhor deixar com a pontuação `0`. Sou nativo em português, mas não sou permitido a responder perguntas neste forum pelo excesso de votos pra baixo, mas lá no inglês estou a caminhar para uma pontuação de 200 em meio ano...

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativei a pergunta, só vim aqui ajudar comentando pra ver se era o que procurava, e não pra ficar sendo acusado e recebendo reclamação, se quer reclamar faça no META, talvez lá apontem o problema, eu não sei qual o problema da pergunta, me parece uma pergunta normal e nem posso imaginar agora o motivo para um downvote, mas é bem mais provavel q seja um motivo justo e não um ataque pessoal.

Comment: Apenas quis desabafar convosco porque acontece muito. Não acusei ninguém nem citei nomes.

Comment: Tudo bem caro Maf, mas aqui não é o lugar, eu não entendo muito do CORE do React, só do uso mesmo, mas se eu conseguir ver o CORE melhor talvez eu formule a resposta, de resto o motivo é pela metodologia que já citei e do "marketing" forçado em cima pra ganhar adeptados que a maioria dos frameworks e toollkits fazem, dão nomes pra coisas q até podiam já existir, não estou dizendo pra não usar, só estou comentando como ocorre o "marketing".

Comment: Peço desculpas por ter falado aqui. Não sabia.Obrigado aos dois pelas respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesses dois casos que você apontou, *não* se trata do que é mais eficiente, mas sim do que está certo e o que está *errado* dentro das convenções adotadas pelo React.

A [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) afirma que qualquer tentativa de atualizar o estado através de uma modificação direta (também chamada de *mutação*) é incorreta, veja:

> #### Não Modifique o State Diretamente
>
> Por exemplo, isto não renderizará novamente o componente:
>
> ```
> // Errado
> this.state.comment = 'Hello';
> ```
>
> Em vez disso, use `setState()`:
>
> ```
> // Correto
> this.setState({ comment: 'Hello' });
> ```

Note que a própria documentação coloca a mutação como algo “errado” e utilizar `setState` como “correto” para atualizar o estado. No fundo, isso acontece porque o React precisa saber quando deve renderizar o componente novamente. Para isso, ele usa o `setState`, que além de atualizar o estado, também *agenda* uma nova atualização. Para saber mais, confira a documentação do [`setState`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Portanto, a segunda opção que consta na sua resposta já se torna inválida no mundo do React, já que o método [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) *muta* o array.

Em suma, a primeira opção é válida. Não há nada de errado com ela.

Com os React Hooks, embora a função `setState` da API antiga não seja mais tão usada, a regra ainda é a mesma. Por exemplo, o *hook* `useState` te dá uma função para que possa modificar o estado ao invés de mutá-lo diretamente. O mesmo motivo se aplica: o React precisa disso para saber quando o componente deve ser renderizado novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta claríssima!